# Trouble posting to plugin controller

Tags: plugin-development, controller

I'm working on a plugin to do subscription billing with paypal. I have the following controller

```
class PaypalSubscription_SubscriptionController extends BaseController {

    public function actionSubscriptions() {
        // This renders a form that collects some info on subscription options
    }

    public function actionSubscribe() {
        $this->requirePostRequest();
        // This takes data and starts a paypal transaction
    }
}
```

I can get to the form by going to `/actions/paypalSubscription/subscription/subscriptions`

I've tried hard coding the url `/actions/paypalSubscription/subscription/subscribe` as well as using `actionUrl('/paypalSubscription/subscription/subscribe')`. The `actionUrl` call prepends `index.php/actions` to the string which is just incorrect, and either way both approaches 404. What am I missing here?

I know that i'm logged in and that works correctly since I can reach the original form and anonymous access shouldn't be turned on, so I don't believe that's the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Does the request requires login?
If it doesn't, you need to add the exception on the controller
`protected $allowAnonymous = array('actionSubscribe');`

Also, did you try adding **admin** to your URL?
`<input type="hidden" name="action" value="/admin/actions/paypalSubscription/subscription/subscribe">`

I was trying to post to an action once through the front-end and it only worked after adding **/admin**

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Possible that it's just that the first is singular the second is plural.</strike>

**Update**
Perhaps the problem is on your form side then. If you're posting from a form, you do not need 'action' as part of the url. Also might check that you have `method="post"` attribute defined.

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    {{ getCsrfInput() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="paypalSubscription/subscription/subscribe">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="subscription-complete">
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: Updated answer with another possibility.

Comment: This seems more plausible. However, when I use the form like this, the POST request is made to the same page. meaning it re-renders the form and does nothing. Maybe this is because my template doesn't use the base templates and such. I'm having trouble getting that to work, but that can be for another question I guess.

Comment: I have no idea if it makes a difference, but what happens if you add the `action` as an attribute to the <form> tag, instead of a hidden input field? I.e. `<form method="post" action="paypalSubscription/subscription/subscribe">`

Comment: ...or you might have some routes messing things up?

Comment: Putting `action` on the form itself then posts to `/actions/paypalSubscriptions/subscription/paypalSubscriptions/subscription/subscribe`

Comment: What do you mean by "not using the base templates"? Are you not extending `_layouts/cp`? If so, that shouldn't really make any difference, in my experience.

Are you positive you don't have any conflicting routes set up in `PaypalSubscriptionPlugin.php`? I can't see any issues with your controller + the form Douglas McDonald pasted, so if those don't work together I'm thinking there's something else tripping you up.

Comment: I don't have any routes defined in my plugin.

Comment: When you use `name="action"` and then omit 'action' in the uri, you are saying that it's re-rendering the same page. It's possible that it's returning an error and that you are not capturing it. You might try printing out all the errors. See [one of the sample forms](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/user-registration-form) in the docs for an example of how to display errors. You might also just print to your plugins log file from the controller to see if it's getting hit at all.

Comment: You can log to your plugin's log file using `PaypalSubscriptionPlugin::log('Form submitted.', LogLevel::Info);` or just throw an exception — `throw new Exception(craft::t("Form submitted"));`